# Getting the last day of the previous year in R?

Tags: r

So the question is how to select the last day of the previous year. I want to set this up to be automatic, cause we might do it for a couple of years.

What I have set up already is this :

```
lastyear <- as.numeric(format(today, "%Y")) - 1
```

Today is just an object with Sys.Date() in it so I don't believe I need to provide code for that? (It's in the format of a date if anyone really wants to know.)

The code I have above gets the previous year fine, but I want something that picks out "2014-12-31" for me.

So, the question repeated would be how can I ***automatically*** pick out the last day of the previous year?

Also, I use lubridate in this script.

Comment: `library(lubridate); as.Date(paste0(year(Sys.Date())-1,"-12-31"))`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a Hadleyverse version:

```
library(lubridate)

last_day_prev_year <- function(x) floor_date(x, "year") - days(1)

last_day_prev_year(Sys.Date())
## [1] "2014-12-31 UTC"
```

I actually up-voted the "base" answer since, well, it's *base* and—as GSee pointed out—less likely to be problematic. The biggest thing the lubridate answer has going for it is readability. It loses on speed, too:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(lubridate)

ldpy_base <- function(x) {
  lastyear <- as.numeric(format(x, "%Y")) - 1
  last_date <- as.Date(sprintf('%s-12-31',lastyear))
}

ldpy_lubridate <- function(x) floor_date(x, "year") - days(1)


mb <- microbenchmark(ldpy_base(Sys.Date()),
                     ldpy_lubridate(Sys.Date()),
                     times=5000)

autoplot(mb) + labs(title="5,000 runs, base vs lubridate")
```

[image]

Comment: @NealC It would probably be better to change the accepted answer to this. Although I am pretty sure my function would work correctly (as long as the input is a Date), using a function like `floor_date` from a package is a better solution since it has been tested for error for most cases.

Comment: Yeah, may have to use this one. 2 lines of code is a lot better. sorry @LyzandeR :P

Comment: You did the right thing NealC. I suggested the same anyway. It is not so much about the number of lines but because functions in packages have been tested for bugs.

Comment: Ahh, alright. Consolidating the script is quite important to me though, even though using certain packages and avoiding other packages is important it is still good to use less code. @LyzandeR

But thank you to both of you!

Comment: @NealC the other solution is only 2 lines because that's the way it was written.  You could easily combine into one and not have to depend on another package. `as.Date(sprintf('%s-12-31', as.numeric(format(x, "%Y")) - 1)`.. Or `as.Date(paste0(as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))-1, "-12-31"))`

Comment: @LyzandeR functions in packages are more likely to change/break than functions in base R.  Base R is tested/used waaaay more.

Comment: @GSee I guess both sides have good arguments on this one. Someone might argue that users are more likely to spot an error on package functions.  Probably, base functions are better on their own but more difficult to spot errors according to how they are being used from users in their functions. It's getting philosophical now :P

Answer (score 9):

Something like this maybe:

```
last_day <- function(x) {
  lastyear <- as.numeric(format(x, "%Y")) - 1
  last_date <- as.Date(sprintf('%s-12-31',lastyear))
}

> a<-last_day(Sys.Date())

> a
[1] "2014-12-31"

> class(a)
[1] "Date"
```

Comment: And you're positive this is going to be automated? From what it looks like to me, it is, but I'm an R Noob :)

Comment: I 've tried it on a few occasions and it is as long as you feed it a Date input :)